# How to disable the New button in property browser of Blend?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, blend

I'm developing a custom control in **WPF**. This control has some properties whose type is custom class.When editting these properties in the Property Browser of Blend, there is a *New* button beside the editting property, While VS is not the case. My question is how to disable this New button in **Blend**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your properties with attributes that tell Blend (and Visual Studio) what to do with them. One of them is the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx).

To hide the property, just add the following:

```
[Browsable(false)]
```

There are a whole lot more attributes in the [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace that you can use to customize the way properties in Blend and Visual Studio the [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [CategoryAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).